# WMIC "call uninstall" slow

Tags: windows, cmd, uninstallation, wmic

Not really a problem, but I would like to find out if I can speed up the uninstall of a product using wmic. There is a program we update frequently which needs to first be uninstalled. To do this remotely, I am running the following command:

**wmic product where name= 'fxd Host' call uninstall /nointeractive**

which does do the job, but depending on the number of applications installed on the pc, can be quit slow in finding and initiating the uninstal of the chosen application or fxd host in this case.

I would expect wmic to initialize the uninstall of fxd immediately, since that is the exact product name listed from the "wmic product list", but it doesn't. The uninstal operation varies on differnet systems, sometimes taking between 5 and 10 minutes to show progress, and sometimes less than 30 seconds.

Manual uninstallations are quick, so I figure I must be missing something with wmic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [`Win32_Product`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) "is not query optimized. Queries such as "select * from Win32_Product where (name like 'Sniffer%')" require WMI to use the MSI provider to enumerate all of the installed products and then parse the full list sequentially to handle the “where” clause. This process also initiates a consistency check of packages installed, verifying and repairing the install."

Comment: If you want to do this in a batch script, start by looking at `reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Currentversion\Uninstall" /s /v DisplayName`.  You'll need to query for the key, and then query again for the uninstall command in the `UninstallString` value. For 32-bit software on a 64-bit system you also need to check `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\...`. Maybe if you search you'll find that someone has already written a batch script for this...

Comment: @eryksun, thanks for information, will attempt adding the registry queries to my batch. Sounds like it might be quicker. Might also go for a third party tool that supports batch commands. Something to think about I guess.